# Android - How to design a view based on mockup

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I am pretty new in Android, but I am an experienced developer.

I am trying to create a table that pretty much looks like this. The content is not important if you don't understand. I have pretty much solved it in the backend. I have retrieved the list and I have created TextViews for each of the columns.

[image: table]

I find it very difficult to design such a page in Android.

I have tried creating a dynamic **TableLayout**. I tried using a layout file first as a template, and add to it dynamically but nothing was displayed. I have also tried to do everything programatically, but I haven't gotten that to work either.
I would like the view to be Scrollable vertically, but before adding more features I wanted the view to work first.

I can show sample of the code.

My layout.xml file

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1"
    tools:context=".TeamReportDetailActivity"
    android:id="@+id/reportDetailTableLayout">

</TableLayout>


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_team_report_detail); //my layout.xml
    //some code for getting the data from database
    putInTableLayout(theData);
}

private void putInTableLayout(ReportDetail rd) {
        TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.reportDetailTableLayout);
        int totalAttGained = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < mAllReports.size(); i++) {
            ReportDTO report = mAllReports.get(i);

             // Create a TableRow and give it an ID
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));   
            tr.setId(1500+i);
            if(report.role.equalsIgnoreCase(GOALKEEPER)) {
                tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            } else if(report.role.equalsIgnoreCase(DEFENDER)) {
                tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            } else if(report.role.equalsIgnoreCase(MIDFIELDER)) {
                tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            } else if(report.role.equalsIgnoreCase(ATTACKER)) {
                tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
            TextView lblRole = new TextView(this);
            lblRole.setId(200+i);
            lblRole.setText(report.role);
            lblRole.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            lblRole.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tr.addView(lblRole);

            //I add all these textviews and then finally I add it to the TableLayout
            // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

This code doesn't display anything. I would really appreciate help in designing a view that will display this table. Also, if anyone can suggest a good resource for learning how to design views in Android, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a TableLayout you should use a more basic layout (possibly LinearLayout) with a ListView embedded within that layout. Once you have a ListView you can use an ArrayAdapter to populate the sub-views of that ListView. Take a look at the [List View](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) tutorial for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using `TableRow.LayoutParams` for your `TextView`. In fact, you should just remove all the lines with `LayoutParams` and use the default, which is going to be `match_parent` width and `wrap_content` height for `TableRow`, and `wrap_content` width and `wrap_content` height for `TextView`.

To enable scrolling, wrap the whole `TableLayout` in a `ScrollView` in your xml, with `match_parent` height for the `ScrollView` and `wrap_content` height for the `TableLayout`, and `match_parent` width for both. As a side note, you'll need to add `android:stretchColumns="*"` to your `TableLayout` so it takes up the whole width.

`ScrollView` is good if you expect your table to have a page or two of data. Beyond that, you'll want to consider using a `ListView`. `ListView` recycles the visible views, swapping in new content as you scroll, so performance is better. The down side of `ListView` is that you will have to specify the widths of the columns explicitly if you want them to line up, while `TableLayout` will do that math for you.